# How can I parse string(ruby hash) to JSON or Array in Rhodes?

Tags: ruby, json, rhodes

I have a mobile application that makes a request to my Rails backend.

The backend JSON returns the information in the following manner:

```
def get_data
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json{
        data = Form.select('column1, column2').where(field:'Rhodes')
        render :json => data
      }
    end
end
```

In my application (Rhodes), I'm using `Rho::AsyncHttp.post` and send to my webview index the data:

```
response = Rho::AsyncHttp.post(
        :url => 'http://xyx.xyx.x.yx:3000/data/get_data.json',
        :headers => {"Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept" => "application/json"}
      )


WebView.navigate( url_for :action => :index , :query => { :form => response['body'] })
```

Now, when I inspect the variable `form` in my webview I get the data in the following structure:

```
<%= @form.inspect %>

"[{\"campo\"=>\"nombre\",\"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"},{\"campo\"=>\"nombre\",\"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"},{\"campo\"=>\"nombre\",\"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"}]"
```

So, I need to show this data in a Table and I want loop this. I tried with `each`:

```
<h2>Data</h2>
<% @form.each do |x| %>
<div><%= x.tipo %></div>
<% end %>
```

But I get the error: `undefined method each for #.`

So, I tried to convert it to a JSON object:

```
data = Rho::JSON.parse(@form)
```

But, I get the following error:

```
JSON error code: 10; Ofset: 9
Trace:
(eval):36:in ´parse´
(eval):36:in '´
lib/rho/render.rb:175:in ´eval_compiled_file´
lib/rho/render.rb:175:in ´render´ [...]
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 with Rhodes 3.5.1.12

### UPDATE

I fix the problem with the function `eval`. Now I can loop the string.
But when I try to print the variable. These not show.

```
<% data = eval(@form) %>
<% data.each do |hash| %>
 <ul>
   <li><%= puts hash['campo'] %></li> #only display the bullets but no the data
   <li><%= puts hash['tipo'] %></li> #only display the bullets but no the data
 </ul>
 <br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Rhodes, but...

You can't use JSON on this string:

```
"[{\"campo\"=>\"nombre\",\"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"},{\"campo\"=>\"nombre\",\"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"},{\"campo\"=>\"nombre\",\"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"}]"
```

because it isn't a JSON serialized object. The `=>` are the giveaway. JSON serializes hashes using `:` to delimit the key/value pairs.

Using `inspect` is probably confusing you because it will turn what looks like an array of hashes into a pseudo-string. I suspect it's really this:

```
ary = [{"campo"=>"nombre","tipo"=>"textfield"},{"campo"=>"nombre","tipo"=>"textfield"},{"campo"=>"nombre","tipo"=>"textfield"}]
```

because if I `inspect ary` I get:

```
# => "[{\"campo\"=>\"nombre\", \"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"}, {\"campo\"=>\"nombre\", \"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"}, {\"campo\"=>\"nombre\", \"tipo\"=>\"textfield\"}]"
```

This is how to iterate over the array of hashes:

```
ary.each do |hash|
  puts hash['tipo']
end
# >> textfield
# >> textfield
# >> textfield
```

Comment: I can't use `each` function over the pseudo-string. Because, when I try loop that variable, I get: `undefined method each for #`

Comment: It's an array of hashes, being represented as a string because you used `inspect`. Don't try to use `each` on a string, use it on a container like an array of hashes, like I show above. Just don't use `inspect` on it.

Comment: My variable `@form` have that structure by default. Because this is dispatched form my backend in rails.
So, I can't alter the characters into that string.